# error on setting up tableau server 10.3 in linux

Tags: ubuntu, tableau-api

I am able to set up tableau server (10.1) in linux by following the steps in this link https://tableauandbehold.com/2016/06/06/tabcmd-on-linux/ . But this doesn't work for tableau server version 10.3. Any idea?